# Definition of subgroup generated by a subset

Tags: group-theory, definition

I'm confused about the definition of a subgroup $(W)$ generated by a subset $W$ of a group $G$. My [textbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471010901) gives:

> Let $(W)$ be the set of all elements of $G$ representable as a product of elements of $W$ raised to positive, zero, or negative integer exponents.

Suppose $W = \{a,b\} \subseteq G$. It's clear to me that, for example, $a^2 b \in (W)$. But is $aba \in (W)$? In general, can elements in the product be repeated when they're not adjacent?

Comment: Yes. $aba\in (W)$. Any finite product on any form and any order.

Comment: Note that according to the definition we do have $aba\in W$. We have a product of three elements of $G$ raised to the positive power of $1$. The definition does not restrict you from using the same factors.

Comment: This the same we do in semigroups, If you know it.

Comment: $(W)$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ which contains all elements in $W$. Since a subgroup is closed under the groupoperation and taking inverses any finite product of elements in $W$ and the inverses of these have to stay in $(W)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $W=\{a,b\}\subseteq G$ where in $G$ is a group so $$\langle W\rangle=\{x_1^{\epsilon_1}x_2^{\epsilon_2}...x_n^{\epsilon_n}\mid x_i\in W,~\epsilon_i\in\mathbb Z,~ n=1,2,3...\}$$ so if $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2=\epsilon_3=1$ and $x_1=a,~x_2=b,~x_3=a$ then $aba\in\langle W\rangle $. If you want any visible example, the following will show the case. Of course the group $G$ below is abelian:

Let $G=(\mathbb Q^*,\cdot)$. Then if $M=\{3,\frac{1}2\}$ we have $$\langle 3,\frac{1}2\rangle=\{3^k\cdot\left(\frac{1}2\right)^l\mid k,l\in\mathbb Z\}$$

Comment: $n$ can be $0$, right?

Comment: $x_0$ is regarded as $e_G$

Comment: I see. Great answer and example!

Comment: I like you're new gravatar! So cute! And charming. ;-)

Comment: Soon you'll see my new (for now) gravatar! :^)

Answer (score 2):

Take as an example the infinite dihedral group $D_{\infty}$, that is the group of maps on $\mathbf{Z}$ given by
$$
x \mapsto \pm x + \lambda,
$$
for $\lambda \in \mathbf{Z}$.

Take $a : x \mapsto -x$, and $b : x \mapsto -x + 1$.

Then $D_{\infty} = \langle a, b \rangle$, and *each element of $G$ can be **uniquely** written as a product* (possibly empty, to represent the identity) 
$$
a b a b a \dots 
$$
where the last term (if the product is non-empty) is either $a$ or $b$. You do not need exponents greater than $1$ here, nor negative exponents, as $a^2 = b^2 = 1$, so that $a^{-1} = a$ and $b^{-1} = b$.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the word "product" is misleading here, because it often refers to elements of the type $a \cdot b$. Actually $(W)$ consists of *words* in $W \cup W^{-1}$ (including the empty word, which gives the neutral element), which are defined to be *iterated* products, or products of arbitrary length, i.e. $a_1 \cdot \dotsc \cdot a_n$ with $a_i \in W \cup W^{-1}$ and $n \geq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

The definition not only, as the other answers explain, includes elements like $aba$; it *must* do so in order to yield a subgroup. A simple example where the set of products using each element at most once would fail to be a subgroup is afforded by the generating set $\{(12),(23)\}\subset S_3$. The powers of $(12)$ are $(12)$ and the identity, and the powers of $(23)$ are $(23)$ and the identity, so the products using each element at most once would include the identity, $(12)$, $(23)$, $(12)\circ(23)=(123)$ and $(23)\circ(12)=(132)$, but not $(13)$; those five elements don't form a subgroup of $S_3$.