# Chevron Symbols in Commutator

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am reading a chapter on Commutator in Group Theory and came across chevron symbols "$\langle$" and "$\rangle$" like these:

> **Question #1:** Let $E$ and $F$ be non-empty subsets of $G$, we set
>   $$[E, F] := \langle [e,f] \mid e \in F, f \in F \rangle.$$

Correct me if I am wrong here: The chevron symbols here do not have special meaning except that they are differentiating from "$\{$" and "$\}.$" The text does not give any explanation.

And then on the same page I saw this problem:

> **Question #2:** Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G.$ Show that $[H, g] = [H, \langle g \rangle]$ for each element $g$ in $G.$

Here the chevron signs have special meaning, they refer to $g$ as generator. If I am correct, how do you go about solving this problem? My understanding that I have to start from the LHS, without assuming that $g$ is a generator. Please help and thanks for your time.

**POST SCRIPT - 1:** ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
I am following hints from "someone you know" in solving Question #2 like these:

$$\begin{align*}[H,g] &= \{hgh^{-1}g^{-1} \mid h \in H \}\\
&= \{hg (g^{n-1})(g^{n-1})^{-1}h^{-1}g^{-1} \mid h \in H \} \\
&= \{h(g g^{n-1})(g^{n-1})^{-1}h^{-1}g^{-1} \mid h \in H \} \\
&= \{hg^n(g^{n-1})^{-1}h^{-1}g^{-1} \mid h \in H \}  \\
&= ... \\
&= ... \\
&= [H, \langle g \rangle] \end{align*}\\$$

How do you go from the 4th. line to the next to move the $(g^n)^{-1}$ to the right side of $h^{-1}$ without resorting to the group being abelian? Thank you again.

**POST SCRIPT - 2:** ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
Since I did not receive any feedback after the Post Script - 1, and since on the subsequent pages of the same class note I saw a very similar question like this:

> Let $G$ be a group and let $g \in G,$ and let $N$ be commutative normal subgroup of $G.$ Show that $[N, \langle g \rangle] = \{[n, g] \} \mid n \in N \}.$

Do you agree with me that there is actually a typo in the Question #2, in that $G$ and therefore $H$ should be declared as commutative in the first place? Thanks for your time and feedback.

Comment: By "they refer to $g$ as [a] generator" you mean "$\langle g\rangle$ refers to the cyclic subgroup generated by $g$."

Comment: Another name for $\langle \rangle$ is *angle brackets*.

Answer (score 4):

In general, if $S$ is any subset of a group $G$, the notation $\langle S\rangle$ refers to the subgroup generated by the elements of $S$, so
$$[E, F] := \langle [e,f] \mid e \in F, f \in F \rangle$$
is the subgroup of $G$ generated by commutators coming from elements of $E$ and $F$. Thus, the notation $\langle g\rangle$ is a special case, in that it refers to $\langle \{g\}\rangle$.

The problem you refer to is asking you to show that $\langle S_1\rangle=\langle S_2\rangle$ where
$$\begin{align*}
S_1&=\{hgh^{-1}g^{-1}:h\in H\}\\
S_2&=\{hkh^{-1}k^{-1}:h\in H,k\in\langle g\rangle\}=\{hg^nh^{-1}g^{-n}:h\in H, n\in\mathbb{Z}\}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: So, the $\langle g \rangle$ refers to generator? Thanks again.

Comment: It means "generated by" rather.

Comment: @someone you know : To "Someone You Know": Could you please help me with the Post Script - 2 above? To all other heavyweights beside "Someone You Know," you are more than welcome to pitch in. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

(1). $[E, F] := \langle [e,f] \mid e \in F, f \in F \rangle$ means the subgroup of $G$ generated by the elements of the form $[e,f], e \in E, f \in F.$

(2). $\langle g\rangle$ means the subgroup of $G$ generated by the element $g.$

You can look at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341509/definition-of-subgroup-generated-by-a-subset) or at any algebra text book.